# create php function that counts clicks and stores value in a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, count, click

Currently trying to store the amount of clicks on buttons and checkboxes into a cookie or a session and there after save it to a database. My idea is to create a counting function for each button and checkbox.

Comment: PHP runs on the server - way before any clicks happens. If you want PHP to do this, you might want to call it with AJAX and store it in the DB there - Else I would suggest you use Javascript for this task

Comment: Thank you I will give it a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the goal of recording hits on page elements you will need to use some form of http request to communicate with the PHP server where the hit will be recorded - either in a database, a volatile session or a file. The example here uses a simple `ajax` function though you could use the more flexible `fetch` api instead.

This demo should give you the basics for creating a solution that does log to db...

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /* store the click in a session or log to DB */
    /*
        using a session will only give accurate information for a single user and a single session
        so to actually record this information for all users and across time and space you really
        need to use a database or, at least some sort of file.

    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['value'] ) && $_POST['action']=='log-click' ){

        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $value=$_POST['value'];
        $svar='clicks';

        /* create the session variable to record hits */
        if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ) $_SESSION[ $svar ]=new stdClass;

        /* assign initial value or increment hit count */
        if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ]->{$name} ) )$_SESSION[ $svar ]->{$name}=1;
        else $_SESSION[ $svar ]->{$name}++;

        /* send something back to the ajax callback - to be processed however suits */
        exit( json_encode( array( 
                'name'      =>  $name,
                'value'     =>  $value,
                'time'      =>  time(),
                $svar       =>  $_SESSION[ $svar ]->{$name}
                )
            )
        );
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            /* very simple ajax function */
            const ajax=function(m,u,p,c,o){
                with( new XMLHttpRequest() ){
                    onreadystatechange=function(e){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                            c.call( this, this.response, this.getAllResponseHeaders(), o )
                        }
                    }
                    let params=Object.keys( p ).map( k=>{
                        return [k,p[k]].join('=')
                    }).join('&');

                    if( m.toUpperCase()=='GET' ){
                        u='?'+params;
                        params=null;                        
                    }
                    open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                    setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    send( params );
                }
            };


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{
                /* Find elements of these types and bind an event listener to each */
                let col=document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="button"], input[type="checkbox"]' );

                /* iterate through each DOM element and assign listener */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( col ).forEach( input=>{
                    input.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                        /* construct arguments for ajax request */
                        let method='post';
                        let url=location.href;
                        let params={ action:'log-click', name:e.target.name, value:e.target.value };
                        let callback=function(r){
                            document.querySelector( 'output' ).innerText=r
                        }
                        let options={};

                        /* make the ajax request */
                        ajax.call( this, method, url, params, callback, options )
                    })
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <fieldset>
                <input type='button' name='bttn_1' value='Click here to win a mystery prize' />
                <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_1' value=1 />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type='button' name='bttn_2' value='Click here to win luxury items' />
                <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_2' value=1 />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type='button' name='bttn_3' value='Click here to win a car' />
                <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_3' value=1 />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type='button' name='bttn_4' value='Click here to win a dream holiday' />
                <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_4' value=1 />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this snippet, I will try to create my own version!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript XHR(ajax) to send click data to the php script
or
Use javascript cookies insted...

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav, I will give it a go and see if I can figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add javascript code that monitor click event and on each click you can fire ajax  call to update counter in database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sachin, I will look into it!